# problem with configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm having problems with creating configurable products in magento 2.0.5. As in, I create the product, I set up the configurations ( by color) yet when I try to save the configurable product and its variations I can't because I am asked to set up a color for the configurable product itself. Which can't be done because that box is greyed out.